# How to pass arguments to contour() inside of plot.surface() [R fields package]

Tags: r, plot, contour

When using plot.surface() of the R fields package I need to change the "method" parameter of the contour() function from its default setting of "flattest" to "simple".

The contour() function is inside of plot.surface().

The plot.surface() documentation says you can pass additional parameters to two other functions appearing in plot.surface(), but no mention of how to pass parameters to contour().

I need to do this because the contour lines in my plot come out straight, resulting in no numbers on the lines. I think I could get numbers to appear on my contour lines if I can change the contour method from "flattest" to "simple" or "edge".

Here is the contour image:

[image]

The code used to generate the image:

```
inMat <- mat_Qe
surface <- list(x = xtick_labs,
                y = ytick_labs,
                z = inMat)
plot.surface(surface, type = "C",
             xlab = "Mean factory efficiency (kL Ethanol / MT Root)",
             ylab = "Mean farm cost (lcu / MT Root)", labcex = 1, col = mapPalette(45))
title(main = "Equilibrium Quantity Map (MT / day)", cex.main = 1)
```

Sorry it's not reproducible, but I think reproducibility is not really necessary in this case. I just need someone to tell me how to pass the method parameter to contour() inside of plot.surface().

Comment: Reproducibility is always desired. For starters, it is not clear from your question which package `plot.surface` comes from.

Comment: @AndersEllernBilgrau plot.surface is from the fields package. I will not be able to provide reproducible code. Should I delete the post? I have found a workaround and anyway I don't want to piss anyone off.

Comment: You can't fabricate some data to use? Your question doesn't need to be exactly the same problem you're working on, but it makes trying to find a solution much easier.

Comment: No, no need to delete the post. But you could simulate or make some data as @mickey suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the example in `?plot.surface`, the following will pass `method` to `contour`. If you run `plot.surface` you'll see that the ellipses (`...`) are given to contour if `type = "c"` although this does not seem to be stated in the documentation. Note this is lowercase `c`, not `C`. With capital `"C"` argument are not passed to `contour`, but to `image.plot`.

```
library("fields")

# Toy data
x <- seq( -2,2,,80)
y <- seq( -2,2,,80)
z <- outer( x,y, "+")
obj <- list(x=x, y=y, z=z)

# Pass method to contour when type = "c"
plot.surface(obj, col="red", type="c", method = "simple")
```

[image]

```
plot.surface(obj, type="c", col="red", method = "edge")
```

[image]